# JavaFx Printing multiple nodes one after another is taking a long time

Tags: javafx

I am using the `javafx.print` library, and am having problems.

Let me explain. I have a `TabPane` with one too many tabs. I am successfully printing each tab on a separate sheet of paper by using `fxPrinterJob.printPage(node);`

My problem lies in the fact that since each page has its own `fxPrinterJob`, it will print page 1, then pauses while it loads page 2, prints page 2, pauses while it loads page 3, etc.. This can take upwards of 30 seconds to print 3 pages.

I have attempted to make the same `fxPrinterJob` print each page, but I get a long list of errors, which looks like resource locking and I feel isn't worth posting here.

I am not doing anything weird or "clever" in the setup of the `PrinterJob`, so I will not post any actual code but rather give pseudo-code as I feel my problem lies in the logic or potentially just some knowledge I don't have yet.

```
Scenario A -> Not working
1) Setup the `PrinterJob fxPrinterJob` variable.
2) Grab the Tab pane and loop through each tab
    a) Grab the content of each tab and do some maths so it fits to one page
    b) Call `fxPrinterJob.printPage(tabNode);` to print the tab.
3) When loop is finished, call `fxPrinterJob.endJob();`

Scenario B -> Works, but prints slowly.
1) Grab the Tab pane and loop through each tab
    a) Setup the `PrinterJob fxPrinterJob` variable.
    b) Grab the content of each tab and do some maths so it fits to one page
    c) Call `fxPrinterJob.printPage(tabNode);` to print the tab.
    d) When loop is finished, call `fxPrinterJob.endJob();`
```

The idea is to have it print out as quickly as it would from a normal text document, but it pauses in between the pages. I have no idea why. I can't find any example where someone prints multiple nodes on multiple pages to check that I'm not overlooking something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine all pages into one Pageable document. Then instead of calling printPage() for each tab, call setPageable() and print().

Comment: This answer would work if using `java.awt` printing, but I am using `javafx.print`, which is a bit different. Editing the question to remove the `java` tag and reiterate this so avoid confusion. Thanks for the answer.